# Open pulse, simple schedule meaning

Tags: qiskit

I'm going through the tutorials [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html#2.-Finding-the-qubit-Frequency-using-a-Frequency-Sweep-) and [quantum lab 06_building_pulse_sched](https://lab.quantum-computing.ibm.com/user/5ff4d7e704cc3c00142ece32/lab/tree/qiskit-tutorials/qiskit/circuits_advanced/06_building_pulse_schedules.ipynb) for qubit calibration. The first pulse is as in the image. There's a couple of things that I still don't understand in it.

(a) The curl arrow is an offset, as described in the quantum lab notebook. In the code of qiskit (first reference), does not seem to be an offset added, why it is present?

(b) Somehow I got lost with the parameters. Why the pulse is centered at around 300ns?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a large tutorial. The offset will be set later on. I hope both answers help you :)

a.)

> We will drive the pulses off-resonance by a known amount, which we
> will call detuning_MHz. The measured Ramsey signal should show
> oscillations with frequency near detuning_MHz, with a small offset.
> This small offset is exactly how far away rough_qubit_frequency was
> from the qubit frequency.

```
with pulse.phase_offset(np.pi/2, pulse.drive_channel(qubit)):
                pulse.call(pi_pulse)
```

b.)

The pulse is centered because of this line of code, which means that the span is perfectly synchron. The maximum and the minimum span gets divided by 2, thus you have 2 equal sides. Regardless of the "width", here frequency:

```
center_frequency_Hz = backend_defaults.qubit_freq_est[qubit]
frequency_min = center_frequency_Hz - frequency_span_Hz / 2
frequency_max = center_frequency_Hz + frequency_span_Hz / 2
print(f"Qubit {qubit} has an estimated frequency of {center_frequency_Hz / GHz} GHz.")
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more the b) part?

Comment: Of course, I updated my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. At the end how comes that 4.9GHz become 300ns?

Comment: In this example, yes